# SVN Update Operation Columns in Console Output

Tags: svn

I ran an `svn update` command from a branch I haven't updated in a long time and I found some surprising column formatting for the svn operation. Is there anything being communicated by what column the U,A,D, etc print it?

```
 U   XXX\YYY...
 U   XXX\YYY...
 U   XXX\YYY...
 U   XXX\YYY...
 U   XXX\YYY...
U    XXX\YYY...
 U   XXX\YYY...
 U   XXX\YYY...
 U   XXX\YYY...
U    XXX\YYY...
U    XXX\YYY...
U    XXX\YYY...
U    XXX\YYY...
U    XXX\YYY...
U    XXX\YYY...
U    XXX\ZZZ...
U    XXX\ZZZ...
U    XXX\ZZZ...
A    XXX\ZZZ...
U    XXX\ZZZ...
UU   HHH\LLL...
```

I'm guessing the first column is for files/directories, the second for svn properties? Is there more than two columns or just two? What are they denoting exactly?

Answer (score 2):

Well, looks like it's pretty well documented already, and there are a bunch of columns apparently.

```
svn update --help

  For each updated item a line will be printed with characters reporting
  the action taken. These characters have the following meaning:

    A  Added
    D  Deleted
    U  Updated
    C  Conflict
    G  Merged
    E  Existed
    R  Replaced

  Characters in the **first column** report about the item itself.
  Characters in the **second column** report about properties of the item.
  A 'B' in the **third column** signifies that the lock for the file has
  been broken or stolen.
  A 'C' in the **fourth column** indicates a tree conflict, while a 'C' in
  the first and second columns indicate textual conflicts in files
  and in property values, respectively.
```